# Cannot load images in KASlideShow pod using Xcode 9.4, Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I was trying to used [KASlideshow](https://github.com/O-mkar/KASlideShow-Swift) pod to have a fade in fade out animation in my slideshow but images are not showing in my output. I tried to solve it  with the solution I saw here in stackoverflow but doesn't work for me.[the solution I tried but did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309418/cannot-load-images-from-kaslideshow-pod)

Here's my  code for your reference. Kindly help me to solve it. Thank you

**class ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, KASlideShowDelegate, KASlideShowDataSource {
func slideShow(_ slideShow: KASlideShow!, objectAt index: UInt) -> NSObject! {
    return slideImages[0];
}

func slideShowImagesNumber(_ slideShow: KASlideShow!) -> UInt {
    return UInt(slideImages.count)
}

func slideShow(slideShow: KASlideShow, imageForPosition position: KASlideShowPosition) -> UIImage{
//missing code here
}
```

**declaration**

```
@IBOutlet var whiteView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var slideShow: KASlideShow!

 var slideImages = [UIImage]()
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     slideImages = [
        UIImage(named: "img1.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img3.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img5.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img6.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img8.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img9.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img11.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img12.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img13.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img14.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img15.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img16.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img17.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img18.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img19.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img21.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img22.png"),
        UIImage(named: "img23.png"),

        ] as! [UIImage]

    slideShow.delegate = self
    slideShow.datasource = self


    slideShow.delay = 1
    slideShow.transitionDuration = 0.5
    slideShow.transitionType = KASlideShowTransitionType.fade
    slideShow.imagesContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    slideShow.add(KASlideShowGestureType.tap)


    slideShow.start()
```

**KASlideShow Delegate**

```
func kaSlideShowWillShowNext(slideshow: KASlideShow){
    NSLog("kaSlideShowWillShowNext")
}

/*func kaSlideShowWillShowPrevious(slideshow: KASlideShow){
    NSLog("kaSlideShowWillShowPrevious")
}

func kaSlideDidShowNext(slideshow: KASlideShow){
    NSLog("kaSlideDidShowNext")
}

func kaSlideShowDidShowPrevious(slideshow: KASlideShow){
    NSLog("kaSlideShowWillShowPrevious")
}
*/
```

Comment: I am still fixing the issue and finally the image showed but only one image appear because the fade effect is not working. Anyone who can help me with this issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you need to change datasource method and images array set only name like this

arrslideImages = ["test_1.jpeg","test_2.jpeg","test_3.jpeg"]

func slideShow(_ slideShow: KASlideShow!, objectAt index: UInt) -> NSObject! {

        let ind = NSInteger(index)
        return slideImages[ind] as NSObject;
    }
```

Comment: I encountered error when omitting _UIImage_ in my array. It shows _Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[UIImage]'_, did I miss something?

Comment: Declare image array like this  var slideImages = [String]()

Comment: Thank you for your help it solved the issue somehow. I also inserted _viewDidAppear_ and transfer the _slideshow.start()_ to _viewDidAppear_. The animation is working already. Thank you so much.